# External class call a LitElement component method (passing html template), and component method updates its html template

Tags: javascript, oop, lit-element, lit-html

I need to have an external class comprising of game logic call a LitElement component, and pass it a html template literal which the component will use to update a portion of its own html template literal.

In the code below you will see a method of the component (`navigationRender`) which can be successfully called from within the component.  That same method can also successfully be called from the external `game` class (as illustrated by the console.log).  But, even though it can be called, it is not successfully updating the html template of the component.

Does `navigationRender` need some kind of callback into the scope of `firstUpdated`?  I'm over my head here, and if that is what is needed, then I don't know how to do it anyhow ...

Below is code which has been condensed into a single file.  If you click the "Change Description" button, then you will see the console.log update with the html template that was passed, but not the rendered html text.

```html
<body>
  <front-end></front-end>
</body>

<script type="module">
  import { LitElement, html, css } from 'https://unpkg.com/lit-element?module';
  
  class FrontEnd extends LitElement {
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.renderDescription = html`<p>initialized - 01</p>`;
    }
    render() { 
      return [
        html`<button id="btn">Change Description</button>`,
        this.renderDescription]; 
    }
    firstUpdated() {
      this.game = new Game();
      this.navigationRender(html`<p>DESCRIPTION: So far, working when called from firstUpdated(). But what about when called from the Game class?</p>`);
      this.shadowRoot.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        this.game.newDescription();
      });
    }
    navigationRender(description) {
      console.log(description);
      this.renderDescription = description;
      this.requestUpdate();
    }
  }
  customElements.define('front-end', FrontEnd);
  
  class Game {
    constructor() {
      this.frontEnd = new FrontEnd();
    }
    newDescription() {
      this.frontEnd.navigationRender(html`DESCRIPTION: Although the console.log verifies that this.frontEnd.navigationRender is being called and the data passed, that function is not able to actually update the this.renderDescription when called from the game class.`);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Thank you for your help and suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  Hopefully, this will help someone else.

```html
<body>
  <front-end id="fe-id"></front-end>
</body>

<script type="module">
  import { LitElement, html, css } from 'https://unpkg.com/lit-element?module';
  
  class FrontEnd extends LitElement {
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.renderDescription = html`<p>initialized - 01</p>`;
    }
    render() { 
      return [
        html`<button id="btn">Change Description</button>`,
        this.renderDescription]; 
    }
    firstUpdated() {
      this.game = new Game();
      this.navigationRender(html`<p>So far, working when called from firstUpdated(). But what about when called from the Game class?</p>`);
      this.shadowRoot.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        this.game.newDescription();
      });
    }
    navigationRender(description) {
      console.log(description);
      this.renderDescription = description;
      this.requestUpdate();
    }
  }
  customElements.define('front-end', FrontEnd);
  
  class Game {
    constructor() {
      // this.frontEnd = new FrontEnd();
      this.element = document.getElementById('fe-id');
    }
    newDescription() {
      this.element.navigationRender(html`<p>YAY!!  THIS WORKS!!!</p>`);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: If you wanted to solve this in a more OOP style (and since Game doesn't need to know about the DOM layer yet), it would likely be enough to pass Frontend as a constructor argument for Game. Like this: `this.game = new Game(this);`. `this` is the instance of Frontend. Inside Game's constructor `this.frontEnd = frontend` The reason your first code failed was because you created a new instance of Frontend inside of Game (not a component, just a class instance) which isn't the same one that is created on page load by your markup.